# How to finish program with "Scanner.hasNext" in Java

Tags: java

I'm wondering how the program with "java scanner" can be finished 
especially when I use this with `System.in` and `scanner.hasNext()`

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

For example, when I run the code below on some IDE

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
         int[] arr = new int[3];
         int i = 0;

         // put all the number from scanner to the array.
         while(sc.hasNext()){
              arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();
          }

          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

and input some numbers(for the inputs for scanner) in the console, 
it doesn't stop receiving the numbers.

I wanted to use `sc.hasNext()` for the purpose of after finishing getting some input for the user, putting all the numbers received, as I commented on the code.

How can I finish the scanner getting the input on console?

Comment: In this question you can not put more than 4 input after that you will get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 but if you want to finish scanner getting the input for that you have to create some condition where you int i value doen't satisfy the scanner condition and then your scanner will not ask for the next input.

Comment: @Rhee, did my answer address your problem?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit sure it did! sorry, I am actually almost new to this website so didn't know I have to make check the v sign for the answers...

Comment: @Rhee no worries, glad to help, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Scanner` will continue to read until it finds an "end of file" condition.

As you're reading from stdin, that'll either be when you send an `EOF` character (usually ^d on Unix), or at the end of the file if you use < style redirection.

However, to put the input from the user in your array, can be done by replacing your `while` condition with this:

```java
while (sc.hasNext() && i!=arr.length) {
    arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run while `stdin` (`System.in` in Java) is open. You could close it programmatically if you want but it's usually done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> 
 in the terminal that program is running (Shortcut is for Linux/macOS in Windows console it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> I think).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your while loop and put a conditional break when your number of integers reach array length. Try this,

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();
    if (i == arr.length) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can write it as a simple for loop,

```
// int i = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Here it will be useful for you to understand how sc.nextInt() works.

Whenever sc.nextInt() gets executed, the scanner objects sc looks for an integer and returns the next integer it finds in the stream scanned by sc object. If it doesn't find an integer in the stream, it will throw some Exception.

Now coming to your code, when your while loop gets executed, every time the code gets inside while loop, it calls sc.nextInt() and one integer is read and assigned into the array but as you have declared your array size as 3 only you need to break the loop else it will try to access an index greater than 3 in your array and will result into ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception which you will not want. Due to which I have put that condition in while loop and it breaks as soon as the index reaches 3. Similar thing is achieved in the for loop. Hope my explanation helps. Let me know if you have any queries further.

Another thing you could have done is, change sc.hasNext() to sc.hasNextInt() in your while loop as hasNext() captures any data (integer or non-integer) from the stream and returns true and you would not want it to return true if the next incoming data is not an integer else that will run into exception.

Once you change sc.hasNext() to sc.hasNextInt() in while loop condition, your program will automatically end once you provide 3 integers as input to your program but if user tried to enter more than 3 integers, it will run into ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception as your array length is limited to 3 only. Hence you need that condition if (i==arr.length) { break; } So your while loop can also be like this,

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();
    if (i == arr.length) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your store the user's input inside a fixed size (4) structure, you can use a `for` loop, 
after all this is the case to use it:

> when the number of repetitions is predefined

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the condition for hasNext as it will always return true after entering an input.

You should have a condition on array length.

try this

```
                int[] arr = new int[3];
                 int i = 0;
                 while(i<arr.length)
                     arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();

                  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a condition in while as you limit your array to a specific length so when it reach this length t can't take any more input and it will just close the loop and print your array
like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] arr = new int[3];
     int i = 0;

     // put all the number from scanner to the array.
     while(sc.hasNext() && i < arr.length){
          arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();
      }

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```